# is part of module FirebaseAnalytics ignoring import

Tags: swift, firebase-analytics

I followed the instructions to install Firebase Analytics with cocopoad but it doesn't recognize the code.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        return true
    }
```

**ViewController.swift**

[image]

Comment: Name your ViewController something else and I would submit an issue with Firebase. Seems odd that they would leave such a generic name in their package